# Hide duplicated rows in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to hide redundant entries in a join of two Pandas DataFrames. It can either be deleted from DataFrame or just be hidden for the view.

Assume we have two or more processing steps. To simplify the example, lets call them `train` and `test`. See the colors in the data as unique identifiers for a particular run.

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
train = dict(
    blue_model=dict(
        p_1=0.1,
        p_2=2
    ),
    green_model=dict(
        p_1=0.3,
        p_2=5
    )
)
test = dict(
    yellow_test=dict(
        model='blue_model',
        q_1=1,
        mse=0.1
    ),
    black_test=dict(
        model='blue_model',
        q_1=10,
        mse=0.2
    ),
    gray_test=dict(
        model='green_model',
        q_1=10,
        mse=0.25
    ),
)
```

We can now look at each step:

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train).T
train_df
```

[image: train table]

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test).T
test_df
```

[image: test table]

To get a complete overview, I can now join on the unique model ID.

```
overview = test_df.join(train_df, on='model', sort=True)
overview.reindex(columns='model p_1 p_2 q_1 mse'.split())
```

Current output:

[image: current output]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function aptly named `mask` does just this.

```
overview.mask(overview == overview.shift(), '')
```

Alternatively, use `df.where` -

```
overview.where(overview != overview.shift(), '')
```

```
                   model  p_1 p_2 q_1   mse
black_test    blue_model  0.1   2  10   0.2
yellow_test                         1   0.1
gray_test    green_model  0.3   5  10  0.25
```

Don't assign this back to anything, this sort of data representation is only useful for display, nothing more.

Comment: @MaxU Thank you...:)